# How can I make my forms mix together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'm trying to implement **auto complete search box** to my existing search form.
How can I mix them together?

**My existing search form**

```
  <%= form_tag communities_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   <div class="input-append">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class =>'input-xlarge search-query', :placeholder => 'keyword' %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

**auto complete form**

```
<%= form_for :community do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :community_title, autocomplete_community_title_communities_path %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: Note that I use the gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

**communities_controller.rb**

```
autocomplete :community, :title, :full => true
```

Comment: I couldn't think of any because these are totally different type of forms:( that's the point that I'm stucked with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
 <%= form_tag communities_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   <div class="input-append">
    <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'search', params[:search], autocomplete_community_title_communities_path, :class =>'input-xlarge search-query', :placeholder => 'keyword' %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

I think all of the form_for methods have a corresponding  *_tag method than can be used inside  form_tag.

form_for just does some additional magic.

Comment: thanks. I tried this but it didn't do anything **<%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class =>'input-xlarge search-query', :placeholder => 'keyword' %>**

Comment: I bet it threw an error that it didn't find the auto complete method for search.   I am guessing you have auto_complete_for :community, :title in your controller?  What plugin are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I've just updated and added more info to my question. please check that.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Not sure what the route is going to be. But hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! could you please make it whole part using my code from question